# Complex Numbers Identity

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $a,b$ be non-zero complex numbers with:

$$a2^{|a|}+b2^{|b|} = (a+b)2^{|a+b|}$$

Show that $a^6 = b^6$.

I gave it a go, but to no avail.

Comment: I believe all solutions are of the form $a+b=0$ or $|a|=|b|=|a+b|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that $a+b=0$ always gives a solution for which $a^6=b^6$.

If $a$ and $b$ are real, we can assume without loss of generality that $a=1$. We get $2+b2^{|b|}=(1+b)2^{1+|b|}$, so $2^{1-|b|}+b=2(1+b)$, so $2^{1-|b|}-b=2$. By piecewise analysis, we find $b=0$ or $b=-1$. But $a$ and $b$ are required to be non-zero, so we have $a+b=0$.

From now on, assume $a+b\neq0$. By rotation, we may assume without loss of generality that $a+b$ is positive and real. Then $a2^{|a|}+b2^{|b|}=(a+b)2^{|a+b|}$ is also positive and real. Since $a$ and $b$ are not both real, neither is real. It follows that $2^{|a|}=2^{|b|}$, so $|a|=|b|$.

Write $a=re^{i\theta}$ and $b=re^{-i\theta}$. We get $a+b=2r\cos(\theta)>0$. So the equality becomes $$2r2^r\cos(\theta)=2r\cos(\theta)2^{2r\cos(\theta)},$$ so $r=2r\cos(\theta)$. This gives $\theta=\frac{\pi}3$, so $a^6=b^6$.

Comment: With the WLOG assumptions, why is $(a+b)$ real? Doesn't this make the assumption that $ r = $?

Comment: @CalvinLin Very good point, that was quite a fatal flaw. I think the proof is correct now, though.

Comment: Now, how does it follow that $2^{|a|} = 2^{|b|}$?

Comment: We have $\mbox{Im}(b)=-\mbox{Im}(a)$ and therefore $0=\mbox{Im}(a2^{|a|}+b2^{|b|})=\mbox{Im}(a)(2^{|a|}-2^{|b|})$.